# How to change system name "Ubuntu" in System Information

Tags: 16.04, system

Good after noon, can anyone tell me please, how to change system name "Ubuntu", version "16.04", release and logo in System Information? I'm really need to change these things in Ubuntu. I'm have Ubuntu 16.04 fresh new installed. I installed Ubuntu with Unetbootin without Usb,DVD from Windows. I using it from Hard Disk ext-4 partition with dual boot Windows 7 NTFS.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1304384/edit) and include the information about how you installed Ubuntu? Are you using it from a Live USB? Are you using Multipass?

Comment: Why would you need to change these?

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 16.04 reaches EoL or End of Life in 4 months or April 2021. Best to install 20.04 or even 18.04.https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases